# reading and writing files using flags in command line in c

Tags: c

My program needs to parse command line arguments and then read contents of a file and/or write those contents to another. The user must enter the commands using flags,where i stands for reading a file and o for writing, like this:

```
./program -isample -ofile
```

Errors:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fputc’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
 {
   int opt = 0;
   FILE *file = NULL;
   FILE *text = NULL;
   char ch[200];

   while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) 
    {
      switch(opt) 
       {
          case 'i':
           {
              file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
              while(fgets(ch, 200, file) != EOF)
              {
                printf("%s\n",ch);
              }
              fclose(file);
           }
           break;
          case 'o':
           {
             file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
             text = fopen(argv[2], "w");
             do
              {
                 ch = fgets(file);
                 fputc(ch, text);
              }while (ch != EOF);
             fclose(file);
             fclose(text);
           }
           break;
          case '?':
          {
            if (optopt == 'i') 
             {
               printf("\nMissing mandatory input option");
             } 
            else if (optopt == 'o') 
             {
               printf("\nMissing mandatory output option");
             }
            else 
             {
               printf("\nInvalid option received");
             } 
          }
           break;
       }
    }

 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think you should tell us what the error actually is? Please include the *exact* error message. Keep that in mind for next time. But your error is because you are passing a `char *` to `fputc` instead of a `char`. You also cannot do `ch = fgets(file);`. `ch` is an array and its value (as opposed to its contents) cannot be modified.

Comment: Don't do the file reading and writing in the `getopts` loop. Use `getopts` to set the filename variables for the input and output. Then after you finish processing the arguments, open the two files, and use a loop to read from one file and write to the other.

Comment: "I'm not feeling well. I went to a doctor and he told me some gibberish. Can you give me the medicine I need to get better?"

Comment: @kaylum the errors were: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type and  passing argument 1 of ‘fputc’ makes integer from pointer without a cast. Sorry I will put errors in here next time. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Barmar so getop loop to get the files, open them and then loop them to read and write. Thanks!

Comment: @immibis Not quite, im still learning c that is why i asked for any help.

Comment: @Soulreaper_10 My comment refers to the way you didn't post the errors in the question. By the way, questions (and answers) *can* be edited.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has several problems:

- you should parsing all arguments before copying: there might be a `-o` option after the `-i` option.
- The filename should be `optarg`
- `fgets` returns `NULL` at end of file
- `printf` will duplicate the `\n`, you should use `fputs`.
- `fputc` does not take a buffer
- `fgets` takes 3 arguments.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *infile = NULL;
    char *outfile = NULL;
    FILE *file = stdin;
    FILE *text = stdout;
    char ch[200];

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
          case 'i':
            infile = optarg;
            break;
          case 'o':
            outfile = optarg;
            break;
          case '?':
            if (optopt == 'i') {
                fprintf(stderr, "Missing mandatory input option\n");
            } else
            if (optopt == 'o') {
                fprintf(stderr, "Missing mandatory output option\n");
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option received\n");
            } 
            break;
        }
    }
    if (infile) {
        file = fopen(infile, "r");
        if (file == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file %s: %s\n", 
                infile, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (outfile) {
        text = fopen(outfile, "r");
        if (text == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open output file %s: %s\n",
                outfile, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    while (fgets(ch, 200, file) != NULL) {
        fputs(ch, text);
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(text);
    return 0;
}
```